# Writing to a text file C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, text-files, fixed-length-record

I have the following values

```
A = 1, 
B = (NULL of 7 characters), 
C = denimRocks , 
D = Yes789, 
E = (NULL of 2 characters), 
F = ATR.
```

I want to write these to a line of a textfile with ***A*** starting at position 1 of the line.***B*** starting at position 2, ***C*** at position 8 and so on.

I want to show blank spaces for the nulls.
I tried using streamwriter but I cant get to acheive what I want to do.

Help please.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
 string a=string.Empty;
    StreamWriter yourStream = null;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            yourStream = File.CreateText("D:\\test1.txt"); // creating file
            a = String.Format("|{0,1}|{1,2}|{2,7}|......", "A", "B", "",......); //formatting text based on poeition
            yourStream.Write(a+"\r\n");                        
            yourStream.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

string.Format and the [composite formatting rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) allow to align a string exactly as you wish:

```
 string A = "1";
 string B = "";
 string C = "denimRocks";
 string D = "yes789"
 string E = "";
 string F = "ATR";

 string result = string.Format("{0}{1,7}{2,10}{3,6}{4,2}{5,3}", A,B,C,D,E,F);
 Console.WriteLine(result);
```

In this way you get every piece of information aligned exactly in the spaces reserved for them and writing to a file is just a matter to open the appropriate stream and write the resulting string